# Python - Could Not Determine Platform Error

Tags: python, sensors, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am using the following tutorial to make a moisture sensor using a Raspberry Pi 4: https://www.instructables.com/Measuring-Soil-Moisture-Using-Raspberry-Pi/

When I have run my code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "/home/pi/project.py", line 5,
      in <module> am = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk = 11, cs = 8, miso = 9, mosi = 10)     
   File "home/pi.......Adafruit_MCP3008/MCP3008.py" line 41, in __init__ 
      gpio = GPIO.get_platform_gpio() 
   File "/home/pi......Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py", line 426, in get_platform_gpio
      raise RuntimeError('Could not determine platform.') 
 RuntimeError: could not determine platform.
```

I understand this has something to do with the code as per each "File" line i.e. the Adafruit code.
Have searched all over for an answer, but can't seem to find anything.
Does anyone know how to fix these errors please?

Comment: This might be because the GPIO library you are using is deprecated. Maybe this can help: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/issues/16

Comment: Oh no! Hmm.......this looks like I'd need to get more devices? Any ideas if I can still build something using existing components?

Answer (score 1):

The library for MCP3008 you are using is deprecated, that's why it doesn't detect the newer RPi platform. Try the library mentioned in [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython) tutorial instead.